# Symfony2 production environment: Mapping exception due to custom User class not found in chain configuration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm developing a bit complex Symfony2.1 based app, with connection to two different databases (with two entity managers, one connected to Oracle and the other one to PostgreSQL) and a custom User class (with a custom password encoder).

I've managed to have it running correctly in dev environment, but whenever I try to run it in production environment I'm getting the next error:

**Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: The class 'MyFirm\UserManagerBundle\Entity\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces  (uncaught exception)**

My security and encoders in app/config/security.yml:

```
security:
  encoders:
    MyFirm\UserManagerBundle\Entity\User:
        id: myfirm_usermanager.password_encoder

  providers:
    user_db:
        entity: 
            class: MyFirm\UserManagerBundle\Entity\User
            property: username
```

The doctrine.orm section in app/config/config.yml:

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    default_entity_manager: user_config_db 
    entity_managers:
        event_db:
            connection:   event_db
            mappings:
                MyFirmEventManagerBundle: ~
        user_config_db:
            connection:   user_config_db
            mappings:
                MyFirmUserManagerBundle:  ~
```

And finally, this is the final Exception log:

```
Exception trace:
 () at C:\SF2_project\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException.php:38
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException::classNotFoundInNamespaces() at C:\SF2_project\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain.php:114
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain->loadMetadataForClass() at C:\SF2_project\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php:112
 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata() at C:\SF2_project\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:302
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() at C:\SF2_project\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:205
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() at C:\SF2_project\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php:268
 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata() at C:\SF2_project\app\cache\prod\jms_diextra\doctrine\EntityManager_5075a0dd6e27a.php:345
 EntityManager5075a0dd6e27a_546a8d27f194334ee012bfe64f629947b07e4919\__CG__\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata() at C:\SF2_project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\EntityUserProvider.php:39
 Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\EntityUserProvider->__construct() at C:\SF2_project\app\cache\prod\appProdProjectContainer.php:1132
 appProdProjectContainer->getSecurity_User_Provider_Concrete_UserDbService() at C:\SF2_project\app\bootstrap.php.cache:211
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at C:\SF2_project\app\cache\prod\appProdProjectContainer.php:1121
 appProdProjectContainer->getSecurity_User_Provider_Concrete_ChainProviderService() at C:\SF2_project\app\bootstrap.php.cache:211
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at C:\SF2_project\app\cache\prod\appProdProjectContainer.php:1105
 appProdProjectContainer->getSecurity_Authentication_ManagerService() at C:\SF2_project\app\bootstrap.php.cache:211
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at C:\SF2_project\app\cache\prod\appProdProjectContainer.php:552
 appProdProjectContainer->getSecurity_ContextService() at C:\SF2_project\app\bootstrap.php.cache:211
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at C:\SF2_project\app\cache\prod\appProdProjectContainer.php:1002
 appProdProjectContainer->getTwigService() at C:\SF2_project\app\bootstrap.php.cache:211
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at C:\SF2_project\app\cache\prod\appProdProjectContainer.php:30
 appProdProjectContainer->getAssetic_AssetManagerService() at C:\SF2_project\app\bootstrap.php.cache:211
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at C:\SF2_project\vendor\symfony\assetic-bundle\Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\CacheWarmer\AssetManagerCacheWarmer.php:33
 Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\CacheWarmer\AssetManagerCacheWarmer->warmUp() at C:\SF2_project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate.php:47
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate->warmUp() at C:\SF2_project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheWarmupCommand.php:64
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheWarmupCommand->execute() at C:\SF2_project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:238
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at C:\SF2_project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:193
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at C:\SF2_project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:78
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at C:\SF2_project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:106
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at C:\SF2_project\app\console:22
```

Has somebody any clue? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Finally, after too much time, I found the solution for this: you have to add the entity manager name to the security definition with the manager_name option:

```
security:
  encoders:
    MyFirm\UserManagerBundle\Entity\User:
        id: myfirm_usermanager.password_encoder

  providers:
    user_db:
        entity: 
            class: MyFirm\UserManagerBundle\Entity\User
            property: username 
            manager_name: user_config_db
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems it is a bug in Symfony2: the default entity manager must be named "default" if you want it to work in Production environment as the default entity manager.

After changing the doctrine.orm section in app/config/config.yml to:

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
      event_db:
        connection:   event_db
        mappings:
            MyFirmEventManagerBundle: ~
      default:
        connection:   user_config_db
        mappings:
            MyFirmUserManagerBundle:  ~
```

everything works.

Comment: I've already done: [https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5724](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5724)

Comment: By the way. Does anyone have this problem too? At the Symfony list they cannot reproduce it...

Comment: Great. Maybe try reproducing it yourself, on a different machine? It could be particular to your OS or PHP version. Maybe also disable any accelerators you have, and check if it is exhibited on the CLI as well as in the browser.

Comment: When I got this error, it was because I had not added a new bundle (the one that was erroring) to the mappings in config.yml - You need to do this if you have the gedmo extensions

Comment: Finally I found it wasn't an error: look at the other answer